# Magmi multi-store import

Tags: magento, magmi

first of all, thank you for providing Magmi, it really helps us keeping our products up to date on daily basis.

I would like to ask you one question - We want to sell our products in Hungary and I want to ask you, how should we configure .csv files in order to have product names in different language? So far we havent done anything particular, I just set up some store management settings, so our .hu version is reachable using url.

Additional info:

Magento Store management setting:

Website Name
Store Name
Store View Name

ourshop.hu
Hu
Magyar

ourshop.sk
Sk
Slovenčina

We fill up these attributes in mamgi csv files:
sku,
_attribute_set,
_type,
magmi:delete,
_product_websites,
status,
visibility,
name,
url_key,
description,
short_description,
enable_googlecheckout,
category_ids,
weight,
price,
special_price,
special_from_date,
tax_class_id,
manage_stock,
use_config_manage_stock,
VeÄľkost:drop_down:1,
size,
brand,
spinview,
labeldiscount,
thumbnail,
small_image,
image,
media_gallery,
media_gallery_reset

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at using the "store" column?

The documentation is not bad: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column

> The store column in magmi accepts **store view codes** , one or several.

And also an example:

```
store,sku,attribute1,attribute2
"admin","0001","value1","value2" <= sets default values for attributes attribute1 & attribute2 for sku 0001
"sv1","0001","value1","value2"  <= sets values for attributes attribute1 & attribute2 for store view sv1 for sku 0001
"sv1,sv2","0002","value1","value2" <= sets values for attributes attribute1 & attribute2 for store view sv1 & sv2 for sku 0002
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: i have two store : https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg  and my csv format : https://snag.gy/Q9ZEme.jpg. still not image import